# MudDrawer does not close when bound to state

Tags: html, user-interface, web, blazor, mudblazor

I got an MudDrawer which looks like this:

```
<MudDrawer Open="GlobaleState.IsDrawerOpen">
    <MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="mt-1">Title</MudText>
    </MudDrawerHeader>
    <NavMenu />
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudDivider />
    <MudContainer>
        <MudToggleIconButton />
    </MudContainer>
</MudDrawer>
```

It is Toggled by the AppBar:

```
<MudAppBar>
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="OnIsDrawerOpenChanged" />
</MudAppBar>
```

This works fine in normal display size. But on mobile or with strong zoom it is not possible to deactive the MudDrawer Overlay. When I had two-way-binding without the State it worked.

[image]

**Wheres the problem? Is a Binding missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay is part of the [MudDrawer component](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Drawer/MudDrawer.razor).

When the overlay is clicked it [sends the new value](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/54c6a11c10b4a1e8fb447f54b534f8a707f877e7/src/MudBlazor/Components/Drawer/MudDrawer.razor.cs#L314) as false

So in order for the drawer to close when the overlay is clicked you need to handle the `OpenChanged` EventCallback.

```
<MudDrawer Open="GlobaleState.IsDrawerOpen" OpenChanged="HandleOverlayClick">
    ///
</MudDrawer>
@code
{
    void HandleOverlayClick(bool newValue)
    {
        if(!newValue) 
        {
            //handle your GlobaleState.IsDrawerOpen
        }
    }
}
```